# Mobile app for emergency video

Tags: android, video, mobile

Let's say that I'm witnessing an event that I have to immediately record to the cloud. Maybe a traffic accident where the hitting driver is trying to get away without giving his details, or a police officer violating someone's right, or a fight that's breaking out, or any other kind of illegal activity for which I'd like to immediately get video evidence.

Taking video in my phone's camera app is unsatisfactory for a few reasons:

1. The video is not backed up immediately to the cloud. What if the perp tries to take my phone away, destroy it, delete the video, etc?
2. Taking a video takes too many clicks. You have to go into the camera app, switch to video mode, press record. This can be hard when you're fumbling and can't miss a second. I want to click just one button on my main screen.
3. I can't text or call for help while a video is being taken by the camera app.

I'd like to have an emergency video app that tackles these problems. I want to take a video and have it uploaded live to my Dropbox, as it's being taken. If the bandwidth isn't big enough, then at least upload portions, or upload stills, and then queue the uploading of the actual video.

**Does anyone know of a mobile app like that, for Android?**

Comment: Could you check whether [Eyewatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eyewatchbasic) fits your needs? According to the app's description, it a.o. offers to send audio/video to emergency contacts in a crisis situation.